# Why hibernate session flush method is committing data in Data base?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria

I Just wanted to know why hibernate is committing the data into data base when
flush method is calling, even though I did not use any transaction statements.

Comment: Are you executing some change to an entity immediately followed by doing a query? By default, Hibernate executes a preemptive flush of the action queue before executing a query to guarantee that the query returns the proper state for all selected entities.

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain it is the flush call that is committing? What I have experienced is that hibernate automatically commits any changes when your code finishes running. So it may not actually be the flush call, it may just be that any changes are getting persisted all the time anyway. Try taking the flush call out and see if it still persists.